# Swift - How can I add an expand a nested dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, tuples, swift2

I have want to add en entry to this kind of Array/Tuple/Dictionary `data`:

```
var i=0
var data = [("foo", ["first": 1, "second": 2]), ("bar", ["first": 1, "second": 2])] 
var newData = [(Int, [String: AnyObject])]()
for (key, value) in data {

    newData.append((i, value))

    i = i+1
}
```

The for loop is changing the "key" of the tuple which is AnyObject to an Int.
I want the Tuple to have the key as dictionary too.

```
[("foo", ["first": 1, "second": 2]),
 ("bar", ["first": 1, "second": 2])]
```

turns into

```
 [(1, ["first": 1, "second": 2]), 
  (2, ["first": 1, "second": 2])]
```

and what I want is:

```
 [(1, ["first": 1, "second": 2, "key": "foo"]), 
  (2, ["first": 1, "second": 2, "key": "bar"])]
```

Comment: How is `newData` defined?

Comment: The way you write your objects, they are not correctly nested. This cannot work: `[(...[...)...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from

```
let data: [(String, [String: AnyObject])] = [
    ("foo", ["first": 1, "second": 2]),
    ("bar", ["first": 1, "second": 2])]
```

this is a variants that doesn't require a separate counting variable

```
let newData = data.map({ (var e) -> [String: AnyObject] in
    e.1.updateValue(e.0, forKey: "key")
    return e.1
}).enumerate().map({ ($0.0 + 1, $0.1) })
```

The `enumerate` call could also be moved to the front which makes the block signature a little less compact, however.

```
let newData = data.enumerate().map { (var e) -> ((Int, [String: AnyObject])) in
    e.1.1.updateValue(e.1.0 , forKey: "key")
    return (e.0 + 1, e.1.1)
}
```

Both variants result in

```
[(1, ["first": 1, "second": 2, "key": "foo"]),
 (2, ["first": 1, "second": 2, "key": "bar"])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = [("foo", ["first": 1, "second": 2]), ("bar", ["first": 1, "second": 2])]

var i = 0
var newData = [(Int, [String: AnyObject])]()
for (key, value) in data {

  var newValue : [String:AnyObject] = value
  newValue["key"] = key
  newData.append((++i, newValue))
}

print(newData)
```

or with the Swift `map` function

```
var i = 0
let newData = data.map { (key, value) -> (Int, [String: AnyObject]) in
  var newValue = value
  newValue["key"] = key
  return (++i, newValue)
}

print(newData)
```